# Difficulty with HTML forms processed with PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

I am currently working on a project for class to create a database and then create form based queries using HTML and PHP. I made the database in MAMP and the form displays, but upon entering any info to be processed it goes to another page that says: "Page isn't working. Localhost unable to handle this request. HTTP error 500"

I'm fairly new to PHP and HTML and I've looked at a lot of different ways to create the forms and process them and I can't seem to get any of them to work. I've looked at it for 2 days and I'm still unsure where my problem is. Could anyone point me in the right direction to fix it?

The code is, for HTML:

```
    <form action="AddCustomer.php" method="POST">
        <input name="C_ID" type="text" placeholder="Customer's ID" />
        <input name="Fname" type ="text" placeholder="First name" />
        <input name="Lname" type ="text" placeholder="Last name" />
        <input name="PNum" type="text" placeholder="Phone number" />
        <input name="Add" type="text" placeholder="Address" /> 
        <input name="D_O_B" type="text" placeholder="Date of birth" />
        <input name="Email" type="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input name="Username" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
        <input name="Password" type="text" placeholder="Password" />
        <input name="CreatedDate" type="text" placeholder="Created On" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
```

And for my PHP:

```
<?php
  DEFINE('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
  DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', '');
  DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
  DEFINE('DB_DATABASE', 'food_ordering');

  $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
  if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  $c_id='$_POST[C_ID]';
  $f_n='$_POST[Fname]';
  $l_n='$_POST[Lname]';
  $p_n='$_POST[PNum]';
  $ad='$_POST[Add]';
  $dob='$_POST[D_O_B]';
  $email='$_POST[Email]';
  $u_n='$_POST[Username]';
  $p_w='$_POST[Password]';
  $c_d='$_POST[CreatedDate]';

  $sql = "INSERT INTO Customer (Cust_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Phone_num, Address, DOB, Email, Username, Password, CreatedDate) 
  VALUES ('$c_id', '$f_n', '$p_n', '$ad', '$dob', '$email', '$u_n', '$p_w', '$c_d');

  if($conn->query($sql) == TRUE){
    echo "New record created sucessfully";
  }
  else{
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }

  $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: remove single quotes outside each `$_POST`

Comment: You could've saved time and google,  "how to process form in php". There are ample examples on this

Comment: Error 500 usually means a syntax error, and yes, you do have them.

Comment: You should also put a closing " on your `$sql` variable

Comment: Shouldn't you close the `$sql` with `)";` instead of `);`

Comment: As mentioned - your missing a closing quote from your SQL statement - `'$c_d');`.  A good IDE would show this up in your code.

Comment: @Akintunde I did google, but all the examples I found were using different formatting and I had questions about the formatting but nobody in particular to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all you have a few mistakes in your php code:

You are loading your `$_POST` variables as a string. Put the outer quotes in the `$_POST` itself.:

- e.g. `'$_POST[C_ID]'` becomes `$_POST['C_ID']`

You also aren't properly closing your SQL query (`$sql`). This is the reason your PHP code in your IF/ELSE statement is showing as strings. After the last insert value close it like this: `");`. So change this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Customer (Cust_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Phone_num, Address, DOB, Email, Username, Password, CreatedDate) VALUES ('$c_id', '$f_n', '$p_n', '$ad', '$dob', '$email', '$u_n', '$p_w', '$c_d');
```

Into This:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Customer (Cust_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Phone_num, Address, DOB, Email, Username, Password, CreatedDate) VALUES ('$c_id', '$f_n', '$p_n', '$ad', '$dob', '$email', '$u_n', '$p_w', '$c_d')";
```

All of your other code looks good to go to me (assuming your table names are correct). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a ton, got the query working fine now. Apologies for the rather simplistic question but I appreciate the time people have taken to answer